# How can I exclude class hidden and noprint rows while filtering

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, hidden

I have a table which contain some hidden and no printable cells.
And I have a script that search in this table and shows wanted cells,
but this script can't exclude hidden and noprint `<td>`s.
Can you help me about this problem?

```js
var $rows_ku = $('#ku_list tr');
$('#search_ku').keyup(function() {
  var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

  $rows_ku.show().filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    return !~text.indexOf(val);
  }).hide();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
  .hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="activeuserlist" class="col m12">
  <div class="card grey white">

    <div class="col s12 m2 l12 grey lighten-4 black-text">
      <div class="input-field col s10 ">
        <i class="material-icons prefix astron-text">&#xe8b6;</i>
        <input type="text" id="search_ku" placeholder="Filter">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="card-action">
  <table id="ku_list" class="bordered responsive-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="hidden">Entry</td>
        <th data-field="id">Kullanıcı Adı</th>
        <th data-field="id">IP adresi</th>
        <th data-field="mac">Mac Adresi</th>
        <th data-field="session">Bağlantı Başlangıç</th>
        <th data-field="activity">Son İşlem Tarihi</th>
        <th class="noprint" data-field='action'>Hareket</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="hidden">3b5970d4fa815391</td> <!-- DONT WANNA SEE IN RESULT -->
        <td>5081@otel</td>
        <td>192.168.26.101</td>
        <td>4c:7c:5f:04:6c:16</td>
        <td>2016-05-12 09:47:55</td>
        <td>2016-05-12 14:33:07</td>
        <td class="noprint"><a href="#modalkes" onclick="SetId('3b5970d4fa815391');" class="btn-floating red  modal-trigger"><i class="material-icons">&#xe047;</i></a>
        </td>  <!-- DONT WANNA SEE IN RESULT -->
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hidden">3dd66a5ec453e31d</td>  <!-- DONT WANNA SEE IN RESULT -->
        <td>6082@otel</td>
        <td>192.168.26.214</td>
        <td>34:51:c9:bc:f0:1e</td>
        <td>2016-05-12 10:12:02</td>
        <td>2016-05-12 17:32:30</td>
        <td class="noprint"><a href="#modalkes" onclick="SetId('3dd66a5ec453e31d');" class="btn-floating red  modal-trigger"><i class="material-icons">&#xe047;</i></a>
        </td>  <!-- DONT WANNA SEE IN RESULT -->
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hidden">108587eeb185d040</td>  <!-- DONT WANNA SEE IN RESULT -->
        <td>6104@otel</td>
        <td>192.168.26.51</td>
        <td>90:fd:61:49:89:bc</td>
        <td>2016-05-12 10:22:52</td>
        <td>2016-05-12 17:31:50</td>
        <td class="noprint"><a href="#modalkes" onclick="SetId('108587eeb185d040');" class="btn-floating red  modal-trigger"><i class="material-icons">&#xe047;</i></a>
        </td>  <!-- DONT WANNA SEE IN RESULT -->
      </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

In this case the header (i.e: **thead**) content always display.

```
    var $rows_ku = $('#ku_list tbody tr');
    $('#search_ku').keyup(function() {
       var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

       $rows_ku.show().filter(function() {
          var text = $(this).find('td:not(.hidden,.noprint)').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
          return !~text.indexOf(val);
   }).hide();});
```

The selector **td:not(.hidden,.noprint)** exclude the hidden and noprint classes.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but, still can see  rows which contain noprint or hidden element when I search

Comment: I have put the working code on jsfiddle please refer the link:
https://jsfiddle.net/Saravanakumar/qa2zeo7o/

Comment: The above fiddle work as usual like your previous code except the search string in hidden and noprint class elements.
or do you want to hide the 'hidden and noprint' class elements when the search string occur in that row?

Comment: Oops sorry.Yes it works perfect. My bad, I dont forget to edit refresh php page. Thanks so much